# MySQL: Access denied for user 'userName'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I am having an issue with creating and grating permissions to a user using phpMyAdmin. I am having a Java swing application and it need to connect to this database.

How I created the user and granted the permission are below, step by step.

1. Open phpMyAdmin
2. Go to 'Users' tab.
3. Click on `Add New User`
4. Give the user name, select `Any Host` as the host (so the % is displayed in its text box), and mention the password. `Any host` is because remote access required.
5. Select `Select` under `Global Privileges` - `Data`
6. Click on `Go`
7. Now I am in the `Users` tab starting page again.
8. Click on `Edit Privileges` on my newly created user.
9. Select the database under `Database-specific privileges`
10. Tick everything under `Database-specific privileges`, `Data` section.
11. Click on `Go`

Now, whenever my Java application connects to this, it gives the below error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'userName'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is how I connect to the database, in my Java application

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":3306/databaseName","user","password");
```

Here,for the variable `ip`, I tried both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` but still no good. What have I done wrong?

I noticed the connection works fine if I select `Localhost` instead of `Any Host` in step 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- After you have made your user.
- Click edit priviliges.
- Change Any Host for Localhost.
- Apply your priviliges.
- Scroll to the bottom and
- make sure that "keep old one" is selected and press Go.

Comment: No, it is just the way it is. Any Host does not include Localhost.

Comment: OK. Imagine I am connecting remotely via a VPN, in this case, will it work? I mean the `Any Host` thing?

Comment: Yes. You will have two users, one for Any Host that will work remotely and one for Localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permissions to the userName@localhost in mysql.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO userName@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, mysql server doesn't get a 'localhost' from a local connection, you should try :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO 'userName'@'theHostName' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

or in a more risky way:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO 'userName'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and finally

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set any password for the phpmyadmin. if yes please include that in the password field.or you can try lik this

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":3306/databaseName","localhost","");
```

Comment: The JDBC takes the password of the user, not the PHPMyAdmin right? of course user has to log in using his user name and password.