# how to solve Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I hosted my database to a server. now i want to get backup for a table call product_tb. so i used following code. and i got this error msg. all pirivilages are given to the user. data base connection is working. because my site is working well. and i use this on my local xampp. its working on that

> Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

this is my code..

```
include('db.php');
    $table_name = "product_tb";
        $backup_file  = "product.sql";
        $sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql );
        if(! $retval )
        {
          die('Could not take data backup: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Backedup  data successfully\n";
```

Help me to resolve this problem guys

Comment: Can you show me the output of the following query `select user, host from mysql.user;` and `show grants for 'user'@'localhost';`

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269446/mysql-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost/27269505?noredirect=1#comment43009550_27269505

Comment: @Mike : how can i run the query?

Comment: You can use phpmyadmin if available. How do u connect to mysql?

Comment: @Mike : i have cpanel. im using phpmyadmin on that.

Comment: So open up your phpmyadmin and go to SQL tab and execute what I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Using Password 'YES' means, your password is incorrect. Try logging in from root user and reset the password of user1 and try again with new password.

EDIT: This error can also occur due to database privilege issue. Grant access to user1 on database that you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Thank you @Haris 
but all pirivileges were given to the user.

Comment: Did you try to debug using first part of my answer? Checking the password!

Comment: yep bro. but still like that

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error occur due to database privilege issue. Try use GRANT as example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user1 @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: where and how can i run this

Comment: Execute with a sql management as phpMyAdmin. Is a normal sql command

Comment: Can try: $sql = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user1 @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1' WITH GRANT OPTION"; mysql_query( $sql );